# Begginer at OOP - JAVA

Tags: java, oop, enums

I found out the OOP in JAVA just 2 days ago, and now I have a problem that I can not reslove alone.
I have 4 classes for a company, in the 1st class we have the characteristics of an employee(name, salary, exepirience) in the 2nd I made a list and a method to add them in the class with the main using the method, the 3rd class is :

"

```
public class Profession {
    public enum Position {
        Developer, Mechanic, Director
    }
}"
```

So how can I use those Enums in the first class to set the salary?
I mean something like

```
"if (position is Developer{
salary = 5000
}else if (position is Mechanic){
salary = 3000
}"
```

and when I go back in the main and write something like:
veselin. (to have the shortcut to setProfession by using the ENUMS.

Comment: Please specify your other classes as well. It's not clear what you are trying to do with that `Profession`, and why you don't use the enum directly. Is there anything else in `Profession` other than the enum?

Comment: Poor title. Rewrite to summarize your specific technical issue.

Answer (score 1):

You have to have an instance of your enum, currently you only have the "blueprint" of it. Create a field of your Position (I've renamed it PositionTypes) and use that. Also, as a personal preference, I don't like having my enums embedded in classes, since you'd have to prefix the class name every time you use it.

An example:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

class Profession {
    public enum PositionTypes {
        Developer, Mechanic, Director
    }

    private PositionTypes _position;

    public void setPosition(PositionTypes position) {
        _position = position;
    }

    public PositionTypes getPosition() {
        return _position;
    }
}

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Profession p1 = new Profession();
        System.out.println(p1.getPosition());
    
        p1.setPosition(Profession.PositionTypes.Director);
        System.out.println(p1.getPosition());
    
        if (p1.getPosition() == Profession.PositionTypes.Director)
            System.out.println("We made a check!");
    }
}
```

This outputs:

```
null
Director
We made a check!
```